# lxml: Get all leaf nodes?

Tags: python, xml, lxml

Give an XML file, is there a way using `lxml` to get all the leaf nodes with their names and attributes?

Here is the XML file of interest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<clinical_study>
  <!-- This xml conforms to an XML Schema at:
    http://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/html/images/info/public.xsd
 and an XML DTD at:
    http://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/html/images/info/public.dtd -->
  <id_info>
    <org_study_id>3370-2(-4)</org_study_id>
    <nct_id>NCT00753818</nct_id>
    <nct_alias>NCT00222157</nct_alias>
  </id_info>
  <brief_title>Developmental Effects of Infant Formula Supplemented With LCPUFA</brief_title>
  <sponsors>
    <lead_sponsor>
      <agency>Mead Johnson Nutrition</agency>
      <agency_class>Industry</agency_class>
    </lead_sponsor>
  </sponsors>
  <source>Mead Johnson Nutrition</source>
  <oversight_info>
    <authority>United States: Institutional Review Board</authority>
  </oversight_info>
  <brief_summary>
    <textblock>
      The purpose of this study is to compare the effects on visual development, growth, cognitive
      development, tolerance, and blood chemistry parameters in term infants fed one of four study
      formulas containing various levels of DHA and ARA.
    </textblock>
  </brief_summary>
  <overall_status>Completed</overall_status>
  <phase>N/A</phase>
  <study_type>Interventional</study_type>
  <study_design>N/A</study_design>
  <primary_outcome>
    <measure>visual development</measure>
  </primary_outcome>
  <secondary_outcome>
    <measure>Cognitive development</measure>
  </secondary_outcome>
  <number_of_arms>4</number_of_arms>
  <condition>Cognitive Development</condition>
  <condition>Growth</condition>
  <arm_group>
    <arm_group_label>1</arm_group_label>
    <arm_group_type>Experimental</arm_group_type>
  </arm_group>
  <arm_group>
    <arm_group_label>2</arm_group_label>
    <arm_group_type>Experimental</arm_group_type>
  </arm_group>
  <arm_group>
    <arm_group_label>3</arm_group_label>
    <arm_group_type>Experimental</arm_group_type>
  </arm_group>
  <arm_group>
    <arm_group_label>4</arm_group_label>
    <arm_group_type>Other</arm_group_type>
    <description>Control</description>
  </arm_group>
  <intervention>
    <intervention_type>Other</intervention_type>
    <intervention_name>DHA and ARA</intervention_name>
    <description>various levels of DHA and ARA</description>
    <arm_group_label>1</arm_group_label>
    <arm_group_label>2</arm_group_label>
    <arm_group_label>3</arm_group_label>
  </intervention>
  <intervention>
    <intervention_type>Other</intervention_type>
    <intervention_name>Control</intervention_name>
    <arm_group_label>4</arm_group_label>
  </intervention>
</clinical_study>
```

What I would like is a dictionary that looks like this:

```
{
   'id_info_org_study_id': '3370-2(-4)', 
   'id_info_nct_id': 'NCT00753818', 
   'id_info_nct_alias': 'NCT00222157', 
   'brief_title': 'Developmental Effects...'
}
```

Is this possible with lxml - or indeed any other Python library?

UPDATE:

I ended up doing it this way:

```
response = requests.get(url)
tree = lxml.etree.fromstring(response.content)
mydict = self._recurse_over_nodes(tree, None, {})

def _recurse_over_nodes(self, tree, parent_key, data):
    for branch in tree:
        key = branch.tag
        if branch.getchildren():
            if parent_key:
                key = '%s_%s' % (parent_key, key)
            data = self._recurse_over_nodes(branch, key, data)
        else:
            if parent_key:
                key = '%s_%s' % (parent_key, key)
            if key in data:
                data[key] = data[key] + ', %s' % branch.text
            else:
                data[key] = branch.text
    return data
```

Comment: I don't know if there is a built-in function to do exactly this, but you can always loop the node and construct a dictionary with the **key/values** exactly like you expect.

Comment: @Anzel good idea. I'm just trying to work out how to do that... Got as far as `tree = lxml.etree.parse('sample_ctgov.xml')` but then not sure how to loop over the elements in the tree (`for node in tree` doesn't work).

Comment: I may do a simple sample for you in a minute

Comment: please see my answer, I have not taken care of performance nor recursion to loop the nested children but hopefully you get an idea where to start

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Supposed you have done `getroot()`, something simple like below can construct a dictionary with what you expected:

```
import lxml.etree

tree = lxml.etree.parse('sample_ctgov.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

d = {}
for node in root:
    key = node.tag
    if node.getchildren():
        for child in node:
            key += '_' + child.tag
            d.update({key: child.text})
    else:
        d.update({key: node.text})
```

Should do the trick, not optimised nor recursively hunt all children nodes, but you get the idea where to start.

Comment: Thanks! To get root, I do this: `tree = lxml.etree.parse('my.xml'); root = tree.getroot()`.

Comment: @Richard, yes Rich, I have updated a little to reflect this so won't be too confusing

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using the recursive version included in my updated question above, but this got me on the right path!

Answer (score 8):

Use the `iter` method.

http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html#iter

Here is a functioning example.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from lxml import etree

xml='''
<book>
    <chapter id="113">

        <sentence id="1" drums='Neil'>
            <word id="128160" bass='Geddy'>
                <POS Tag="V"/>
                <grammar type="STEM"/>
                <Aspect type="IMPV"/>
                <Number type="S"/>
            </word>
            <word id="128161">
                <POS Tag="V"/>
                <grammar type="STEM"/>
                <Aspect type="IMPF"/>
            </word>
        </sentence>

        <sentence id="2">
            <word id="128162">
                <POS Tag="P"/>
                <grammar type="PREFIX"/>
                <Tag Tag="bi+"/>
            </word>
        </sentence>

    </chapter>
</book>
'''

filename='/usr/share/sri/configurations/saved/test1.xml'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = etree.fromstring(xml)

    # iter will return every node in the document
    #
    for node in root.iter('*'):

        # nodes of length zero are leaf nodes
        #
        if 0 ==  len(node):
            print node
```

Here is the output:

```
$ ./verifyXmlWithDirs.py
<Element POS at 0x176dcf8>
<Element grammar at 0x176da70>
<Element Aspect at 0x176dc20>
<Element Number at 0x176dcf8>
<Element POS at 0x176dc20>
<Element grammar at 0x176dcf8>
<Element Aspect at 0x176da70>
<Element POS at 0x176da70>
<Element grammar at 0x176dc20>
<Element Tag at 0x176dcf8>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this out:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

def crawl(root, prefix='', memo={}):
    new_prefix = root.tag
    if len(prefix) > 0:
        new_prefix = prefix + "_" + new_prefix
    for child in root.getchildren():
        crawl(child, new_prefix, memo)
    if len(root.getchildren()) == 0:
        memo[new_prefix] = root.text
    return memo

e = ElementTree.parse("data.xml")
nodes = crawl(e.getroot())
for k, v in nodes.items():
    print k, v
```

`crawl` initially takes in the root of an xml tree. It then walks all of its children (recursively) keeping track of all of the tags it went over to get there (that's the whole prefix thing). When it finally finds an element with no children, it saves that data in `memo`.

Part of the output:

```
clinical_study_intervention_intervention_name Control clinical_study_phase
N/A clinical_study_arm_group_arm_group_type Other 
clinical_study_id_info_nct_id NCT00753818
```